# Why does is java.lang.URL class not found from ColdFusion 10?

Tags: coldfusion, java-7, coldfusion-10

Using facebook4j and to post a link you must create and supply a URL object. However when I try to do so I get a class not found error. Appears CF10 is running on JRE 7.0.15

For example this throws an error

```
<cfset testurl = createObject("java", "java.lang.URL").init("http://www.google.com") />
```

but this doesn't for a string object

```
<cfset testurl = createObject("java", "java.lang.String").init("http://www.google.com") />
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right after posting of course I find some old documentation mentioning the class name is java.**net**.URL

Comment: Just when you start to think error messages always fib, they throw you a curve ball and tell you the truth ;-)  FWIW, class names are also case sensitive. So `java.net.URL` works, but `java.net.url` would not.